# angular-calendar header help needed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-calendar

Im trying to implement mattlewis92's angular calendar (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) and I can't figure out what i need to inclide to have a working header component.

Problems:

```
<h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</h3>
this.dateFormatter[method] is not a function
```

but it works when:

```
<h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:('dayViewTitle'):'en' }}</h3>
```

other:

```
TypeError: addFn is not a function
at CalendarNextViewDirective.onClick (calendar-next-view.directive.js:33)
```

same with previus date.

Has anyone suggestion?

Comment: What is `view` in `calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle')`? Is it a string property or variable of the component class?

Comment: A string property. values are: 'month', 'week', 'day'. It should concat the two strings and should give 'dayViewTitle'. whenn its hardcoded ti has no problem. Whenn its like so it's unable to resolbe the angular pipe.

Comment: Can you show in the question the code for the `view` property?

Comment: ```private _view: string;
    public get view(){
      return this._view;
    }
    public set view(view:string){
      this._view = view;
    } ```

Comment: If you try: `public get view(): string { return 'day'; }`, does it work?

Comment: Great. thanks. It does the job but it still undescored with red line(VS Code).

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue `TypeError: this.dateFormatter[method] is not a function` Have you found a solution for this in the mean time?

Comment: I am also using mattlewis92's angular calendar. it is showing full month name and full day name. i need to show short name of month and days like (Su, Mo, Tu) etc. I do not know how to format this. Can you please help? @ConnorsFan